# Unity Arfoundation placed object is not static

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

Added FeatheredPlanes scene from samples to my project.
The problem is: when the content
https://gyazo.com/685b86f10b01e734dac14d57ee7a022e
is per-defined (set the cube or any object before building) - everything works fine.
When the object is set dynamically, my object is loading from the server and then is setting to the "content", then after placing it to the virtual plane - it starts to move if i move my camera.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was model's pivot point.
It was at the center of the model, and all i had to do, is to offset the model, so the bottom part of the model is leveled with the floor.